# SecurityException Permission - not saving image to android device

Tags: java, android

Trying to make a painting app. Everything but the save button is functioning as intended. Whenever I click the save button, it's not saving and I'm getting an error `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=10397, uid=10298 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`.

```
else if(view.getId()==R.id.save_btn){
                //save drawing
                AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");
                saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");
                saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        //save drawing
                    }
                });
                saveDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                saveDialog.show();
                drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");
```

In the manifest I have

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: provide more code to check if you asked for permissions before or no

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just wrap your code like this:

```
 //check permission is granted or no    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
     {
      requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RESULT);
     } 
    else
     {
    //your code
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to write storage permission on Manifest fie.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also for Marshmallow you have to write code for checking and granting storage permission.

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
  }
```

If you need to ask permission then below code works.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Result callback for permission will be.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
    //resume tasks needing this permission
}

}
```

Comment: yes @AmmY is right   Marshmallow  has added some Runtime permission rules .